# How to performSelectorOnMainThread with swift and get a return value without using closures?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch

The function i am trying to run is this:

```
func dateFromSection(section: Int) -> (startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate)?
```

How do i run it using the following and capture the return value without using dispatch functions?

```
performSelectorOnMainThread(aSelector: Selector, withObject: AnyObject?, waitUntilDone: Bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely, positively sure you're **not** already on the main thread, you can do this:

```
var dates: (startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate)?
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    dates = someObject.dateFromSection(section)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `PerformSelectorOnMainThread`? You could have used `dispatch_get_main_queue` instead.

`PerformSelectorOnMainThread` invokes a method of the receiver on the main thread using the default mode.

`dispatch_get_main_queue` returns the default queue that is bound to the main thread.

In your case you should put your function call in `dispatch_get_main_queue` like this, so that you will get back your return values.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 

       let ouptut = self.dateFromSection(YourDate)
       // output contains your return value, which is a closure
    })
```

If you want callback to get reflected in some other part of the code, you can create a local instance of this closure and can assign return value to it like this. Otherwise you can create a global instance and can assign which can be used in other classes.

```
 class YourClass
 {
      //MARK: Local Variables

      var yourDateClosure : (startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate)? 

    func yourFunctionName()
   {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 

         self. yourDateClosure = self.dateFromSection(YourDate)
      })
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the contents of `scrollToDate` and `dateFromSection`, which will give us more clarity on what we are looking into.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` in this case, because it isn't possible to capture the return from it. Use `dispatch_async` instead:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    let dates = dateFromSection(section)
}
```